# XML Schema: what's the default type of an xsd:attribute?

Tags: xml, xsd

In EBUCore schema (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata_standards) there is an attribute named 'version' defined as

```
<attribute name="version" default="1.5">
  <annotation>
    <documentation> The version of the schema for e.g. OAI management.</documentation>
  </annotation>
</attribute>
```

As you see, there is no 'type' defined for it and I wonder, what's the default type for it - `anyType`, `anySimpleType`, `string`, `float`, `double`, ...

W3C spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xmlschema-1-20010502/#section-Built-in-Simple-Type-Definition) is a bit hard to get through:

> The ·simple ur-type definition· is considered to have an unconstrained
>   lexical space, and a value space consisting of the union of the value
>   spaces of all the built-in primitive datatypes and the set of all
>   lists of all members of the value spaces of all the built-in primitive
>   datatypes.

So, maybe someone can tell me, which type to map this attribute to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Attribute Default Type

The type of **XML attributes** in XSD defaults to [`xsd:anySimpleType`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#d0e16395).

**Where's it say that?**

[3.2.2 XML Representation of Attribute Declaration Schema Components](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cAttribute_Declarations)

> The simple type definition corresponding to the  element
>   information item in the [children], if present, otherwise the simple
>   type definition ·resolved· to by the ·actual value· of the type
>   [attribute], if present, **otherwise the ·simple ur-type definition·**.

Then, you can find the connection between **simple ur-type definition** and `xsd:anySimpleType` [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/datatypes.html):

> [Definition:]   The simple ur-type definition is a special restriction
>   of the ur-type definition whose name is **anySimpleType** in the XML
>   Schema namespace. anySimpleType can be considered as the ·base type·
>   of all ·primitive· datatypes.

Yep, one would have hoped it'd have been easier to determine.

### Element Default Type

The type of **XML elements** in XSD defaults to [**`ur-anytype`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#key-urType).