# Impact of XSD Element defined with no type

Tags: xml, xsd

Hopefully a simple knowledge question, but I can't seem to find an answer elsewhere.

What would be the impacts of having an element defined within a schema that was the following

```
<xs:element name"FooBar" />
```

Would it allow any data type or nothing at all?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To quote [the standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#declare-element), regarding how the type is resolved for an element (bolding added for clarity):

> The type definition corresponding to the `<simpleType>` or `<complexType>` element information item in the children, if either is present, **otherwise** the type definition resolved to by the actual value of the type attribute, **otherwise** the type definition of the element declaration resolved to by the actual value of the substitutionGroup attribute, if present, **otherwise** the ur-type definition

In your example, the element would resolve to the [ur-type](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#ur-type-itself), i.e. `xs:anyType`.
This allows any children, possibly mixed with text content, as long as it is well-formed XML.

**Related:** [XML Schema: what's the default type of an xsd:attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29845983/xml-schema-whats-the-default-type-of-an-xsdattribute)